# Access to private field from class instance

Tags: c#, .net

I would like to know why this code is correct and there is possible to add values to private NameList. I thought that private field is inaccessible from class instance.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Test test = new Test();
        test.NameList.AddRange(new[] { "Test" }); // why OK?
        test.Name = "fake";                       // error, OK!
    }
}

class Test
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public List<string> NameList { get; private set; }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: `Name` and `NameList` are both public properties. Why wouldn't you be able to access them?

Comment: Why do you think the `NameList` is private? It has the `public` modifier.

Comment: @Dmitry: `private set;`

Comment: Based on your update you are not changing what `NameList` points to - you are simply mutating it.

Comment: @BradChristie, setter isn't used in the code.

Comment: I don't understand why the OP has received 2 downvotes here. It's not a bad question at all (considering he was unaware of this behaviour). It's also very specific, and on-topic.

Comment: @Dmitry: Was just "Translating" when OP meant when they said/interpreted it to be private.

Answer (score 7):

The property's getter is public. Thus, it returns an object of type `List<String>`, which is mutable. Your code is just modifying that object; perfectly legal.

Declaring the setter private only means that you won't be able to assign a *new* `List<String>` object to `NameList`.

Comment: To extend upon this, may want to add `private List<String> nameList` and add `public List<String> NameList { get { return nameList.AsReadOnly(); } private set { nameList = value; } }`

Comment: It doesn't compile ("Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection<string>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>").

Comment: Yea, I kind of rushed through it. You'll either have to return an `IList<T>`/`IEnumerable<T>` or make your property of type `ReadOnlyCollection<T>`. Aslso, any time you want to manipulate it within your object you'll need to reference the private member.

Comment: I would recommend `ReadOnlyCollection`. If you return an object of type `IEnumerable` (which would normally be my suggestion), there's nothing keeping the caller from casting it back to an `ICollection` and modifying it. Call me paranoid, but it's happened. If you could trust the consumers of your API, you wouldn't bother with access modifiers in the first place.